# Can't use deep-insights cartodb javascript library

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cartodb

I was using sometime ago the deep-insights.uncompressed.js library from cartoDB, but they now included it in the carto product in lib/assets/javascript/deep-insights but I don't know how to use it in my html pages, I've tried to

```
<script src="./deep-insights/index.js"></script>
```

but it says that 'Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at index.js:1'... Any ideas on how do I use it in my pages?

EDIT: [The Github link](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/tree/master/lib/assets/javascripts/deep-insights)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I work at CARTO

That library was never officially released, nor supported. So I guess has evolved into a dependency for BUILDER and cannot be used outside easily. Instead, I would recommend migrating your code to [CARTO.js 4](https://carto.com/documentation/cartojs/). Soon (weeks) we'll release a visual components library to complement it that will make easy to develop dashboards, even tough it won't be easy as it was with Deep Insights.